# RevTex Proceeding Style

Tags: cross-referencing

I'm using the asprev4-1 bibliography style and trying to follow the [Physical Review style guide](https://d22izw7byeupn1.cloudfront.net/files/styleguide-pr.pdf). This mostly works but I am having issues with Proceeding references. In the style it asks for "Author in *Proceeding etc*." however the style seems to ignore authors for proceedings.

This is pretty frustrating as I would have assumed the style guide and the apsrev4-1 default would match up.

Is there a default style I have to use that maybe I'm unaware of? Here is what I'm using at the moment.

```
@proceedings{Barrett_RotationReview,
  title = {\text{B. Barret et al. in} Proc.\ of the International School of 
Physics "Enrico Fermi", Varenna, Italy
      (Varenna, Italy, July 2013)},
  author = {Barrett, B and Gominet, P.-A and Cantin, E and Antoni-Micollier, 
L and Bertoldi, A and Battelier, B and Bouyer, P and Lautier, J and 
Landragin, A},
  volume = 188,
  series = {Atom Interferometery},
  publisher = {IOS Press},
  address = {Varenna, Italy},
  year = {2014},
  pages = {493-555},
  doi = {10.3254/978-1-61499-448-0-493},
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As if the universe wanted to paint me the fool, I found the solution just after posting my question, despite furious Googling before...

The below style using @inproceedings seems to work.

```
@inproceedings{label,
Author = {Smith J. and others},
Editor = {{Publisher}},
Title = {{Proceeding Title}},
Booktitle = {{Proceedings of Conference Title (Acronym YEAR)}},
Series = {},
Year = {{}},
Volume = {{}},
Pages = {{}},
Note = {{Conference Title (acronym),
   City, Country, Date, Year}},
Organization = {},
DOI = {{}},
ISSN = {{}},
}
```